# reloading a page with newly-appended data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom, persistence

On a site I'm working on, I have an administrator panel that allows admins to add list items to existing unordered lists. This is done using an AJAX form with jQuery's `.append()`. The list items are URLs and are inserted into a database using PHP. This part works.

I need to be able to reload the page with the new list items whether or not an admin is logged in (as in, I want the updated lists to be available to all users). I know I can't do this unless I use sessions, cookies, or some kind of local storage/persistent storage utility.

If I decide to use something like persistJS, what is it that I need to be saving so that it can be reloaded later? The whole `<ul>`? The entire document?

If I use PHP sessions, how would I go about it?

Here are some example lists and the form

```
<h3 class="category">
    List 1
</h3>
<ul id="1">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
</ul>
<br />
<h3 class="category">
    List 2
</h3>
<ul id="2">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
</ul>

<form id="addRec_form" action="classes/resources/addResource.php" method="post">
    <p><select name="categoryList" id="categoryList">
        <option value="0">Select a list to add to</option>
        <option value="1">List 1</option>
        <option value="2">List 2</option>
    </select></p>
    <p>Resource name: <input type="text" name="recName" id="recName" /></p>
    <p>Resource URL: <input type="text" name="recURL" id="recURL" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submitAddRec" value="Add resource" id="submitAddRec" /></p>
</form>
```

And the AJAX:

```
$.ajax ({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/classes/resources/addResource.php',
    data: {
        recName: $('#recName').val(),
        recURL: $('#recURL').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data === 'added') {
            function updateLists() {
                var h3ID = $('#categoryList option:selected').val();
                var title = $('#recName').val();
                var url = $('#recURL').val();
                var newListItem = '<li><a href=\"' + url + '\">' + title + '</a></li>';
                $('ul#' + h3ID).append(newListItem);
            }
        }
        else
            $('span#resError').fadeIn(400).text('There was an error adding this resource');
    }
});
```

Again, the PHP works. The AJAX even works, as I can see the new list item being added to the appropriate list. When I refresh the page the new list item isn't there, obviously.

It makes sense that whatever I need to do to save the new DOM state, it needs to be done in the AJAX success section.

I just don't know how to start. Could someone please provide me with some example code for what I am trying to accomplish? It doesn't matter whether it's server or client-side.

Thanks!

EDIT: Is it possible to make an additional AJAX call upon the first's success? As in, upon the first AJAX request's success, a new AJAX call would be made that would use PHP to add the new list item so that it will be present on page reload?

Comment: Is that list is db retrived list?

Comment: No. The lists were already made using HTML. Only the new list items created by using the form are being added to the db

Comment: Hello Nojo....look, the aproach that you should have its to show the lists and items on the page load; you can do that with one php script in many ways.

Comment: @RobertRozas may I see an example?

Comment: You can reuse this code: http://sudobash.net/web-dev-populate-phphtml-table-from-mysql-database/